# Floquet theory PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I recently learned how to prove the following theorem due to Floquet:

Let $\Phi(t)$ be a fundamental matrix solution $\Phi(t)$ of the equation $\Phi' = A(t) \Phi(t)$ ($*$), where $A(t)$ is periodic with minimal period $p$. Then $\Phi(t+p)$ is also a fundamental solution of ($*$) and there exists an invertible matrix $P(t)$ with periodicity $p$ and a matrix $B$ such that $\Phi(t) = P(t) \exp(Bt)$.

Obviously, this is useful to be able to understand properties of the solutions of the ODE system.

On the other hand, I have seen Floquet theory being used (for example [here](https://journals.aps.org/prfluids/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevFluids.1.063601) ) to study linear PDEs (in the paper the authors study a linearised form of Navier Stokes). Could someone point me to some reference where I could read up on the basics of Floquet theory for PDEs? 
I did find a [book](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783764329013) on the topic, but if possible, I would just like to study the basics and am afraid the book may be overly technical. If someone has read the book and can comment on it, I would be very happy as well.

Comment: I am responding to this old post, but I'm mentioning the references in case it can be useful to others. "Periodic Motions" by M. Farkas is a good reference, and so is "Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations" by R. Grimshaw.

Comment: Appendix B of the following paper has a brief explanation of Floquet theory. https://jaijeet.github.io/research/PDFs/2000-TCAS1-Demir-Mehrotra-Roychowdhury.pdf